# Need thoughts on where to implement unique number generation logic in our distributed environment

Tags: uniqueidentifier, distributed-system

We have a unique requirement where we need to create fixed 12 digit unique number for every transaction we process successfully in our current application. The application is set of restful services and has Oracle DB as a data store.

We do have the logic as to how to come up with unique 12 digit number but we are trying to understand where we can fit this logic so that the transactions which are getting executed in this environment gets reference to this unique id.

We figured out that keeping some part of that 12 digit in DB sequence could be an option but that will not work in near future as we would be having multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you have a Sequencer service which is responsible for generating these unique numbers? When a new transaction is created, the entity which manages the transaction can request a unique number from this service and associate this with the transaction.

Comment: Right, but that service needs to be implemented in Non-distributed setup, agree @Andrei ?

Comment: Can you give more details about your question? The service can be used in a distributed setup. This service should allow you do keep track of the highest allocated id.

Comment: Yes, The service can be used in distributed environment but the service itself can not be distributed... there has to be only 1 instance of this service which is getting called, correct? @Andrei

Comment: There is only 1 instance of this service. The service has a single function to generate sequence numbers. This is a common approach in total order multicast algorithms to ensure that all the receivers of the messages deliver the messages in the correct order. In your case if you want to replicate the content of a database across multiple databases. Also, you can use it to generate sequence numbers even if you don't have replication in mind. You can extend this to multiple sequencers as well, but they will need to regularly exchange messages with the latest sequence number